# Jquery inline datepicker select multiple dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm a beginner to javascript and Jquery. I'm using [this plugin](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) for Jquery datepicker. I have used the inline datepicker, wherein I have used the features like change month and year. I would like to select the multiple dates at a time in that inline datepicker. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you read the doc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never use this plugin before, but if you look at this page : [DatePicker with multiple select enabled](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html) you need to pass the following parameter :

```
selectMultiple:true
```

So you can initialize your control with something like that :

```
$('.date-pick')
        .datePicker(
            {
                createButton:false,
                displayClose:true,
                closeOnSelect:false,
                selectMultiple:true
            }
        );
```

Comment: And you can restrict number of selectable dates using: numSelectable:x